# How do I make a batch with a reg query from a .txt file list?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, registry, append

I have a list of software I want to scan for using the name, and I only know how to query 1 item at a time. I want to query both HKLM and HKCU using a .txt file, then output number of entries found, then which ones it found. Currently I only have it appending results to a file.

```
@echo off
Title Scanning Computer
echo Searching for Malicious Software
reg query hklm\software /f "conduit" /s > Results.txt 
reg query hkcu\software /f "conduit" /s > Results.txt 
pause
```

I understand this is basic, and any suggestions and recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you not use one of the applications already existing to scan computers for malicious software? Any batch file solution would be approximately 1000 times slower in comparison to those applications and less safe regarding false positive on usage.

Comment: Any suggestions that only scans and doesn't repair? I am also taking Autoit/AutoHotKey recommendations!

Comment: Anti-virus applications and scanners for malicious software can be configured on what to do when a problematic file or key is found. The default is repair respectively put into quarantine or delete. But it is also possible to configure the action to just report.

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to make my own, for diagnostic only purposes.